# Android Studio Kotlin show next textview integer

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, textview

Im trying to create a generator, when i click the start button, the textview gives me a a random number.
This works great,
but i want to show the numbers still i click stop
so it must give me every few secons a new random number from my mutable List.
How could I do this?
My first opinion was, recursive function.

```
private fun run() {
    var x = 0
    var randomListe = mutableListOf<Int>()
    randomListe.add(Random.nextInt())
    x++
    for (element in randomListe) {
        var x = 0
        val zahlInListe = randomListe[x]
        //     Thread.sleep(1_000)
        // I tried while here
        textView.text = ("${randomListe[x]} \n das ist die Random Zahl moruk\n")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `launch` a `coroutine` block in `lifecycleScope` for this and you can also remove redundant `x` for keeping the current `index` to show the last value, you can use the `last` method of `ArrayList` to get the `last` value in the `list`

Make changes to your `run` method and return a `Job` object from it so you can cancel it later when the user taps on the `stop` button.

```
private fun run(): Job {
    return lifecycleScope.launch {
        while(true){
            delay(1000)

            var randomListe = mutableListOf<Int>()
            randomListe.add(Random.nextInt())
            textView.text = ("${randomListe.last()} \n das ist die Random Zahl moruk\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Now keep the return `job` value in a variable, on calling the `run` method

```
private var job: Job? = null
 
job = run()
```

Call `cancel` on `job` when the user taps on the stop button

```
btnStop.setOnClickListener{
    job?.cancel()
}
```